# Custom Post Type with Subfolder in Custom Theme

Tags: custom-post-types

I've created a custom post type (Projects) in my theme. In theme main folder I have archive-projects.php and single-projects.php but i want to put all inside a subfolder (eg mytheme / projects / archive-projects.php and mytheme / project / single-projects.php) , how can i do it? i tryed to edit functions.php with :

```
$args = array (
    'rewrite' => array ('slug' => 'projects'),
     'has_archive' => 'projects',
);
```

but nothing changed. Wordpress look in the theme folder ( mytheme ) and not in mytheme/projects. Thanks in advance

Comment: the rewrite options have nothing to do with template loading, what you want to do can't be done by setting a flag in `register_post_type`. I would strongly advise against what you're trying to do as it deviates from standards

Comment: thanks for answer, ok so if it does not respect the wordpress standards, I have to leave the two files in the root folder, correct? thanks

Comment: The WP standard is to put them in the root theme folder, rewrite rules have nothing to do with theme templates, rewrite rules are about URLs and only URLs